# PHP email error alert message

Tags: php, forms, email, alert

So I have a died function and I made it echo an alert with an error message.   The problem is after I close the box the code continues and it gives my success message.  if i add `exit;` `died;` or `died();`  it redirects me to a white page...  If I put redirect Header it redirects before I can see the alert box.

Here is the function and the code.

```
 function died($error) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. \nThese errors appear below.\n\n' . $error . '");</script>';  // your error code can go here
}
<?php

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
  $email_to = "admin@domain.com";
  $email_subject = "NEW CLIENT!!!";

  function died($error) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. \nThese errors appear below.\n\n' . $error . '");</script>';  // your error code can go here
  }

  // validation expected data exists
  if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you     submitted.');       
  }
  $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

  $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

  $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required  

  $error_message = "";

  $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.\n';
  }

  $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.\n';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.\n';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

  $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

  function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
  }

  $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

  $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

  $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

  // create email headers
  $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
  'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>

<!---include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: why did you define functions twice ??? it must show an error..

Answer (score 0):

Your script returns nothing because `$_POST['email']` is not set. All your code is inside the conditional block.

The bottom 3 lines close your original if statement, where if `$_POST['email']` is set. This file should be on it's own file for form submission. Have a separate html file with the action to this file. e.g: `<form action="thisfile.php">`

Comment: I am kind of new to this.   It functions as far as sending email.  I want to make an if and else statement but I don't understand where the bottom 3 lines close the } .  Any further guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

send the mail only when no errors were found. As goes for the success message. So an extra ELSE when checking if errors > 0 is added below

Try to place function on a central place not within if statements

And the regex to check email adresses is incorrect. Forexample foo@bar.travel will not match.

```
<?php
   function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
  }
  function died($error) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. \nThese errors appear below.\n\n' . $error . '");</script>';  // your error code can go here
  }


if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
  $email_to = "admin@domain.com";
  $email_subject = "NEW CLIENT!!!";


  // validation expected data exists
  if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you     submitted.');       
  }
  $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

  $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

  $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required  

  $error_message = "";

// below regex used to be a bit valid years ago. not anymore
//      $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';


  if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.\n';
  }

  $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.\n';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.\n';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
  else {
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


  $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

  $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

  $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

  // create email headers
  $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
  'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>

<!---include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php

  }
}
?>
```